# Bootstrap card content gets collapsed in the middle

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, bootstrap-grid

Im trying to design card on my website. Unfortunetly i cant use 100% of my card because somehow the grid system is cutting of the content at the half of the length. This is how it looks like

[image: Gets cut of in the middle]

I need to implement the bootstrap grid system to make it responsive. Here is the code i used for this:

```
 <div class="row flex">
  <div class="col-12 flex">
    <div id="offercards" style="margin-top: 10px; align-items: start" class="card col-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
          <span style="font-weight: bold">Hamburg</span> nach <span style="font-weight: bold">München</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-3" style="padding-top: 10px">
          So, 25.09.2022 9Uhr
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
          <img style="height: 100px; width: 100px; border-radius: 100px" src="../../assets/images/Offers/frau.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4" style="font-weight: bold">
          <i style="color:#3A9B8F" class="bi bi-person"></i>
          3
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4" style="font-weight: bold">
          <i style="color:#3A9B8F " class="bi bi-minecart-loaded"></i>
          50kg
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4" style="font-weight: bold">
          <i style="color:#3A9B8F" class="bi bi-search"></i>
          1,50m x 2m
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
          <i style="color:#3A9B8F" class="bi bi-check-lg"></i>Nichtraucher
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
          <i style="color:#3A9B8F" class="bi bi-check-lg"></i>Keine Tiere
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
          <i style="color:#3A9B8F" class="bi bi-check-lg"></i>Musik
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
          <i style="color:#3A9B8F" class="bi bi-x-lg"></i>Unterhaltung
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-end" style="padding-top: 10px;">
            <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 30px">30€</span>
            <button class="btn btn-primary ml-3">Buchen</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I tried using flex end and changing the column size.

Does anyone have a solution for this? Im running out of ideas.